# Why Python rollbacks code when reading a JSON file

Tags: python, json

So this is my python code:

```
## fixes all ids in a sequence

import json

annotations_folder_source = 'directory/'

category = "car"


new_id = 0

data_fixed = {}
labels_fixed = []

int_frame = 1
end_frame = 500


init_json = int_frame - 1  
end_json = end_frame - 1

for i in range(init_json, end_json+1):
    new_id = new_id
    num_zeros = 6 - len(str(i))
    f_name = '0'*num_zeros + str(i) + '.json'

    f_path_source = annotations_folder_source + f_name

    # load source and target files
    with open(f_path_source) as f_source:
        data_source = json.load(f_source)
    print("Frame: "+str(i)+"\n")
    for labels in data_source['labels']:
        if (labels['category'] == category):
            labels['id'] = new_id
            new_id = new_id + 1
            labels_fixed.append(labels)

    data_fixed = data_source
    data_fixed['labels'] = labels_fixed

    # Closing files
    f_source.close()

    # Saved combined result overwriting f_target
    with open(f_path_source, 'w') as f_source:   
        json.dump(data_fixed, f_source)
    f_source.close()
    print("----------\n")

print("END")
```

The code should access to a folder which contains 500 json files. In each file I want to update an id field with an autoincremental variable (new_id). Each json file looks like:

```
{
    "name": "000448",
    "timestamp": 0,
    "index": 448,
    "labels": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "category": "truck",
            "npoints": 7,
            "box3d": {
                "dimension": {
                    "width": 3.490625,
                    "length": 17.29788867562834,
                    "height": 4.300000000000001
                },
                "location": {
                    "x": 5.019761743421808,
                    "y": -64.47665732636735,
                    "z": 0.30999662173084086
                },
                "orientation": {
                    "rotationYaw": -0.017453292519943295,
                    "rotationPitch": 0,
                    "rotationRoll": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category": "car",
            "npoints": 12,
            "box3d": {
                "dimension": {
                    "width": 1.9140624999999996,
                    "length": 4.414587332055948,
                    "height": 1.7
                },
                "location": {
                    "x": 4.862968749999982,
                    "y": -16.208483685228707,
                    "z": -0.9500000000000003
                },
                "orientation": {
                    "rotationYaw": 0.017453292519943302,
                    "rotationPitch": 0,
                    "rotationRoll": 0.0349065850398866
                }
            }
        },
```

As I said, new_id resets to zero in every for iteration, in stead of keep increasing, and I dont know how to solve it and why it happens. Any idea?

Comment: (1) For one, you never reset `labels_fixed` between the files, so those will keep accumulating. (2) You don't need `data_fixed` or `labels_fixed` at all, since you're modifying the data in-place anyway. (3) For safety and idempotency's sake, you might want to change things so you're not overwriting the original files; overwriting will make debugging quite maddening, since subsequent runs of seemingly the same code could have different results.

Comment: Only with (1) you already stomped my code. Thanks a lot :) ggs

Comment: You do not need `f_source.close()` when using a context manager.

Comment: `new_id = new_id` doesn't do anything.

Comment: `f_source.closed()` is also unnecessary. The `with` statement that opened file ensures the file is closed at the end of the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't quite answer your question, you might want something like this instead... Please see the inline comments. :)

```
import json
import glob
import os

annotations_folder_source = "directory"
annotations_folder_target = "directory-fixed"  # create this directory first
category = "car"

new_id = 0

# This assumes you want to change all of the JSON files in the directory,
# not a given range from 1 to 500. (I boldly assumed it was just for ease of iteration.)
all_jsons = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(annotations_folder_source, "*.json")))

for frame_num, filename in enumerate(all_jsons, 1):
    with open(filename) as fs:
        data = json.load(fs)

    print(f"Frame: {frame_num}")
    for labels in data["labels"]:
        if labels["category"] == category:
            labels["id"] = new_id
            new_id += 1
            print(f"Re-id'd: {labels}")
    dest_filename = os.path.join(annotations_folder_target, os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(dest_filename, "w") as fd:
        json.dump(data, fd)
    print("----------\n")
```